# sum of a filed.function after filter

Tags: python, function, odoo

i was create a module openERP il my class i have 3 colomns:

hour_from( type float), hour_to( type float) and totalhour(fileds.function) in the function i calcul the difference between hour_from and hour_to

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
res = {}
for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
    res[record.id] =  record.hour_to - record.hour_from
return res

 _columns = {
'hour_from' : fields.float('Work from', required=True, help="Start and End time of working.", select=True),
    'hour_to' : fields.float("Work to", required=True),
     'totalhour' : fields.function(_total, type='float', method=True, string='Total Hour'),

}
```

in the xml file i have this  code in the tree record:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <field name="hour_from" widget="float_time" string="Heure début"/>
  <field name="hour_to" widget="float_time" string="Heure fin" />
  <field name="totalhour" widget="float_time"/>
  </field>
</field>
```

it works very well my problem append when i try to filter the tree result by user for exemple

i've the some of hour_to, the sum of hour_from but not the sum of totalhour. well wich i want is different: i want to have only the sum of totalhour.

I hope that i was explain my problem. can some one help mee please?

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'sum' in totalhour field:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <field name="hour_from" widget="float_time" string="Heure début"/>
  <field name="hour_to" widget="float_time" string="Heure fin" />
  <field name="totalhour" widget="float_time" sum="Total"/>
 </field>
</field>
```

Comment: That's good thanks but not this what i want i think that i was describe the probleme with a bad word i'm sorry my problem is when i group the tree result by user i have user(10) hour_from(34 hour_to(45) totalhour()  that's my probleme wich i want is to get in the first ligne after grouped the tree result the sum of total hour not the others sums.

Comment: maybe you should use store attribute for totahour field?